# How to embed a swf on top of a html page?

Tags: html, flash, embed

I want to embed a swf over a html page, like a floating video watching panel. I already have a swf file which will automatically adjust its size according to the browser size, and the swf file is partially transparent. I thought I can just add a div tag, make the position absolute and change z-index bigger, but that doesn't work because the swf just replaced everything that's on the page.

Here's what I did

```
<script>
      swfobject.embedSWF("swf/float.swf", "header", "100%", "100%", "9.0.0");
</script>

<body bgcolor="#000000">
      <div id="header"></div>
      <div id="shell">
          things in my html
      </div>
</body>

#header {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:100;

}
```

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you get your sizing to work properly you will need to set the *wmode* to *transparent* to be able to see what's behind the flash, if you don't it's background will be opaque.

This is a quick copypaste from the [swfobject docs](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation), but it should get the point across:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var flashvars = {};
var params = {wmode : "transparent"};
var attributes = {};

swfobject.embedSWF("myContent.swf", "myContent", "300", "120", "9.0.0","expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem with this is that the CSS doesn't work well with `<object />` tags.  The `swfobject.embedSWF` turns the `<div id="header"></div>` into an `<object />` tag with a bunch of attributes that might be effecting the CSS.  If you create a wrapper DIV around the header DIV and apply the CSS to the wrapper DIV, everything works better.  You also need to add 100% width and height in the CSS.  Here's the revised source:

```
<script>
    swfobject.embedSWF("swf/float.swf", "header", "100%", "100%", "9.0.0");
</script>

<body bgcolor="#000000">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header"></div>
        </div>
    <div id="shell">
        things in my html
    </div>
</body>

#wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:100;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: it's still not working right, after i add the wrapper, it will cut the page to half, half is the swf and half is the html. also if I add the width:100% and height:100%, all of my buttons are disabled...